# Fattal error: Vcl.ExtCtrls was compiled with a different version of Vcl.Consts?

Tags: delphi

I have Delphi project coded in v.10.3.3 Starter version. Now when I try to compile this project in v. 10.4 Community Edition I get a Fatal error and following error message:

[dcc32FatalError]...dpr(25):F2051 Unit Vcl.ExtCtrls was compiled with a different version of Vcl.Consts.sCannotAddToEmpty

What's going on here? v.10.3.3 compiles just fine, but v. 10.4  does not. Is there something changed in v. 10.4? How could I fix this error? Could you help with this? I really would to carry on my project as soon as possible.

Comment: Please see [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/F2051_Unit_%25s_was_compiled_with_a_different_version_of_%25s.%25s_(Delphi))

Comment: Maybe you added some unit of old delphi on project directory or unit path.